# new project from existing source xcode4

Tags: xcode4

I'm very new to xcode development.  I've created a small application, but want to use everything in this project to make a new project so I don't have to redo everything.  How would you do that?  I want the new project to be exclusive with a new name so that i can change the views.  From this point on keeping both projects seperate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project and drag and drop the code you want to keep and check the check box which asks whether you want to copy the files.